# google map Travel mode: request a ride

Tags: android, google-maps

is it possible to change travel mode google maps to request a ride tab on android when click button from my app?

[image]

i used :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?daddr="+    mLocation.latitude + ","+ mLocation.longitude +"&f=d&dirflg=r"));
startActivity(intent);
```

but parameter dirflg only limited to:

```
dirflg=h - Switches on "Avoid Highways" route finding mode.
dirflg=t - Switches on "Avoid Tolls" route finding mode.
dirflg=r - Switches on "Public Transit" - only works in some areas.
dirflg=w - Switches to walking directions - still in beta.
dirflg=d - Switches to driving directions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems (request a ride -> ta**X**i) and:

```
dirflg=x - Switches on "request a ride tab" - only works in some areas.
```

and you can use intent with request like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=-7.328306+112.715478&daddr=Jl.+Frontage+Ahmad+Yani+Siwalankerto&dirflg=x"));
startActivity(intent);
```

to get result like that:

[image: Request a ride (taXi) tab]

(replace `-7.328306+112.71547` by `mLocation.latitude + "+"+ mLocation.longitude` for your LatLng in request)

Comment: hi thanks for the great answer, is it possible to chose go-jek first instead grab?

Comment: @RonnySulistio Hi! You are welcome! Unfortunately, seems not: it's external service. But need to try. It's a good question so create it - may be someone knows.